# Delete comment in chat

Tags: support, chat

How can I delete my comments IN A CHAT?
Deleting REGULAR comments (on a question) is easy - there's a button right next to it, but I can't find the delete option in chat.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See [this post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/270490/how-to-delete-own-comment-in-chat-room) on the main Meta site.

Essentially, you can only delete a comment within two minutes (unless you are a moderator).

Comment: If you have a strong need to delete something later than the 2 minutes, flag it for a moderator and explain why.